# Ionic : Card component Body preview limited characters

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, limit

I want to make a limit body preview to x number of characters in ionic Card component and add a "read more" button, i consumed a json data and show data in the home page.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component     } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PostsProvider } from '../../providers/posts/posts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public postsProvider: PostsProvider) {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.postsProvider.getPosts()
    .then(data => {
      this.posts = data;
    });
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
        Our News
      </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content no-padding no-border no-margin0>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/760/300"/>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title class="post-title">
          {{ post.title }}
        </ion-card-title>
        <p class="post-content">
          {{ post.body}}
        </p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-content>
```

is there any option in the card component to do the job or should develop it by my self ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substring()` function in Javascript. It takes 2 integer parameters and returns a slice of the old string starting from the index of the first parameter up to the index of the second parameter.

eg:

```
'Hello World!'.substring(0, 5)
```

returns:

```
'Hello'
```

So in your case, you will need to create a filter that uses the substring function to slice up the first n characters that you want to show in your preview.